# Postgres: for each row evaluate all successive rows under conditions

Tags: postgresql, window-functions

I have this table:

```
id | datetime            | row_number 

1    2018-04-09 06:27:00   1
1    2018-04-09 14:15:00   2 
1    2018-04-09 15:25:00   3
1    2018-04-09 15:35:00   4
1    2018-04-09 15:51:00   5
1    2018-04-09 17:05:00   6
1    2018-04-10 06:42:00   7 
1    2018-04-10 16:39:00   8 
1    2018-04-10 18:58:00   9
1    2018-04-10 19:41:00   10
1    2018-04-14 17:05:00   11
1    2018-04-14 17:48:00   12 
1    2018-04-14 18:57:00   13
```

I'd count for each row the successive rows with time <= '01:30:00' and start the successive evaluation from the first row that doesn't meet the condition.

I try to exlplain better the question.
Using windows function lag():

```
 SELECT id, datetime, 
        CASE WHEN datetime - lag (datetime,1)  OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY datetime)   
        < '01:30:00' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS count
        FROM table
```

result is:

```
id | datetime            | count 

1    2018-04-09 06:27:00   0
1    2018-04-09 14:15:00   0 
1    2018-04-09 15:25:00   1
1    2018-04-09 15:35:00   1
1    2018-04-09 15:51:00   1
1    2018-04-09 17:05:00   1
1    2018-04-10 06:42:00   0 
1    2018-04-10 16:39:00   0 
1    2018-04-10 18:58:00   0
1    2018-04-10 19:41:00   1
1    2018-04-14 17:05:00   0
1    2018-04-14 17:48:00   1 
1    2018-04-14 18:57:00   1
```

But it's not ok for me because I want exclude row_number 5 because interval  between row_number 5 and row_number 2 is > '01:30:00'. And start the new evaluation from row_number 5.
The same for row_number 13.

The right output could be:

```
id | datetime            | count 

1    2018-04-09 06:27:00   0
1    2018-04-09 14:15:00   0 
1    2018-04-09 15:25:00   1
1    2018-04-09 15:35:00   1
1    2018-04-09 15:51:00   0
1    2018-04-09 17:05:00   1
1    2018-04-10 06:42:00   0 
1    2018-04-10 16:39:00   0 
1    2018-04-10 18:58:00   0
1    2018-04-10 19:41:00   1
1    2018-04-14 17:05:00   0
1    2018-04-14 17:48:00   1 
1    2018-04-14 18:57:00   0
```

So right count is 5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use a recursive query for this:

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE tmp AS (
    SELECT
        id,
        datetime,
        row_number,
        0 AS counting,
        datetime AS last_start
    FROM mytable
    WHERE row_number = 1
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
        t1.id,
        t1.datetime,
        t1.row_number,
        CASE
            WHEN lateral_1.counting THEN 1
            ELSE 0
        END AS counting,
        CASE
            WHEN lateral_1.counting THEN tmp.last_start
            ELSE t1.datetime
        END AS last_start
    FROM
        mytable AS t1
    INNER JOIN
        tmp ON (t1.id = tmp.id AND t1.row_number - 1 = tmp.row_number),
    LATERAL (SELECT (t1.datetime - tmp.last_start) < '1h 30m'::interval AS counting) AS lateral_1
)
SELECT id, datetime, counting
FROM tmp
ORDER BY id, datetime;
```